# How to use dlldata.c generated by MIDL?

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to make a C++ COM server, and use it from C#. I added an interface, a coclass, and a coclass implementing the IClassFactory for the coclass. I generated the TLB, and imported it into C#. I also added DEFINE_PROXY_DLL
REGISTER_PROXY_DLL flags to the C++ compilation.

As far as I understand the dlldata.c contains the DllGetClassObject, which should return my IClassFactory object, which it does not. I get CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE error. Should I implement my own DllGetData (then what should I do with dlldata.c?). I am a little bit puzzled.

Comment: I do believe you need to implement your own DllGetClassObject, it can't be automatically generated because it needs to know the type of the IClassFactory implementation for each coclass. But even then there are other issues you'll run into, like marshalling. There are few people in the world who know how to make a full-fledged C++ COM server without ATL. I suggest saving your time and just use ATL.

Comment: The generated dlldata.c only needs to be used when you build your own proxy for the COM server.  I'd estimate you'll read that sentence as Greek at about 95%.  There is a learning curve to COM and you've only climbed the first step.  Using ATL and the wizards built into VS can help you skip several of those steps.  Not otherwise a workaround for spending at least 3 months to learn the basics.